# Units of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 3]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Prove that the number of units of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{3}]$ is infinite, i.e. $a^2 -3b^2=1$ has infinitely many integer solutions.

Can you help me?

Comment: you tried something?

Comment: a=2, b=1  , a=7, b=4 ...

Comment: no, no.. what i mean is i would suggest you to look at the following case : try proving that , if $(a,b)$ is a solution then you can get another solution from this... may be first step would be to see some relation between your examples... $a=2,b=1$ and $a=7,b=4$

Answer (score 6):

**Hint.** unit $\times$ unit is unit.

Comment: this would be really helpful as you have already seen two solutions... :)

Answer (score 3):

As you have noted in the comments, you know that $u=2+\sqrt 3$ is a unit in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 3]$. Then $u^n$ are all units. They are all distinct because $u>1$.

You can write a recursion for expressing $u^n = x_n + y_n\sqrt 3$. Write $u_{n+1}=u_n u$ and get

$x_{n+1}=2x_n+3y_n\qquad x_0=1$

$y_{n+1}=\hphantom2 x_n+2y_n\qquad y_0=0$

It is true that all units are powers of $\pm u$ because $u$ is the smallest unit greater than $1$, but this is harder to prove.